# How to tell the compiler to search some libs inside /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

Tags: compiling, make, wayland

I try to compile a project, I got the [source files](https://github.com/michaelforney/swc) from git hub.

But when I launch `make`, the compilation complains that the dependency on `wayland-server` is not met.

However, I have wayland installed.
On my system, `libwayland-server.so.0` is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

When looking at the `Makefile` of the project, I see that the variable `LIBDIR` is set to `/usr/lib`

So I suspect the compiler is not searching for `wayland-server` lib inside `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

What is the way to go so as to fix this compilation problem ? Should I modify the make file, in which way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command

```
Export LIBDIR=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LIBDIR
```

And try again.
If it works, put this line in your ~/.bashrc